# Default environment for screen is /bin/sh when it should be /bin/bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, gnu-screen

I'm trying to invoke a program to run on startup in /etc/rc.local which runs two commands:

1. Start a detatched screen using `screen -dmS name`
2. Send a command to that screen using `screen -S name -X stuff command`

However the command relies on environmental variablesbeing set. I've set these EXPORT commands in both the root .profile and the root .pam_environment file. For reference they are:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64`

However the started screen cannot see these variables and errors out with `error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` - which is what I'd expect if these variables weren't set.

The trouble is I can't figure out *why* they're not set. My best guess is that, for some reason, the screen is using `/bin/sh` (which is what it reports if I `echo $0`, whereas the root's default shell is `/bin/bash`

The weirder thing is that this only happens for a screen instantiated like this at boot. If I use the same command to start a detached screen it all works correctly (and uses /bin/bash) with no problems with environmental variables.

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix? I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe your `$SHELL` is not set or set to `/bin/sh`? Or you have a `shell` set to `/bin/sh` in your `.screenrc` file?

See `screen`'s documentation:

> ```
> -s program
> ```
>
> > sets the default shell to the program specified, instead  of  the  value  in  the
> >                 environment  variable  `$SHELL`  (or  `/bin/sh`  if not defined).  This can also be
> >                 defined through the `shell` `.screenrc` command.  See also there.

And there:

> `shell command`
>
> > Set the command to be used to create a new shell.  This overrides  the  value  of  the
> >            environment variable `$SHELL`.  This is useful if you'd like to run a tty-enhancer which
> >            is expecting to execute the program specified in `$SHELL`.  If the command begins with a
> >            `-` character, the shell will be started as a login-shell. Typical shells do only minimal initialization when not started as a login-shell.  E.g. Bash will not  read  your
> >            `~/.bashrc` unless it is a login-shell.

i.e. adding the following line to `.screenrc` in your home folder should set the default shell of screen to `bash`

```
shell /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the -s flag to strictly force /bin/bash did the trick. However this is still confusing as the value for $SHELL is set as /bin/bash and running screen from a terminal starts it as /bin/bash also. It's only in this one scenario that screen starts in /bin/sh/ and I'm still unsure why.

Comment: Maybe it starts too early at boot when $SHELL is not yet populated?

Comment: maybe it's a user preference vs system preference. since the "system" is not really root, is it?

Comment: I experienced the same problem when running `screen` inside a docker container. `$SHELL` was set to `/bin/bash` and I had a `.screenrc` with the line `shell $SHELL` but still new screen sessions were using `/bin/sh`. In the end explicitly setting `shell /bin/bash` in my `.screenrc` meant that screen started with bash and so did new screen sessions.